# Is it still normalized db schema? database

Tags: database, rdbms, normalization, 3nf

I have the following db-schema .

**FILE**, **GROUP** and **BLOCK** represent the object structure of the XML file.
**FILE** is the root. 
**GROUP** has FK to **FILE**. 
**BLOCK** has the one FK to **GROUP** and the another one FK to **UNIT**.

**UNIT** groups "similar" **BLOCKs** from diffrent **GROUPs** in the context of **FILE**.

The data base is currently in 3NF. Yet I would like to know which **UNITs** belong to **FILE**.id=1. To do this yet, I have to make a query which joins all 4 tables. To optimize this schema, I can create the new relation **UNIT** n--FK-->1 **FILE**. Yet my query joins only two tables on the optimized db-schema.
And here is the question: is this DB(with this new FK) still in 3 NF ? What the theory says?

```
BLOCK  n--FK-->1  GROUP  n--FK-->1  FILE
 n 
 |
 FK    
 |    
 1  
Unit
```

or

```
            +--------+
      +-----|  File  |.....+
      |     +--------+     .
      |                    .
     /|\                  /.\
 +--------+           +--------+
 | Group  |--+     +--|  Unit  |
 +--------+  |     |  +--------+
             |     |
            /|\   /|\
           +---------+
           |  Block  |
           +---------+
```

Comment: Can you try to display your table structure rather than explain it?  It's difficult to follow an explanation of a set of tables.

Comment: @user229570, what is the relationship between GROUP and UNIT? At the moment, there appears to be a many-to-many relationship between them - adding the FILE.ID foreign key to UNIT produces two parallel hierarchical relationships from FILE to BLOCK. Such parallel relationships are not forbidden by 3NF, but normally resolve to one hierarchical relationship, as one of the intermediate tables is normally in a hierarchical relationship with the other intermediate table - unless, of course, there is a *true* many-to-many relationship between them.

Comment: Thank you for Edit. I wanted to do this, but my rank was too low. UNIT represents the second parallel hierarchy. I will add the probe of the data in a moment when my rank is enough. Probably we have to even add this new relation (UNIT -> FILE) because it's parallel hierarchy. So it is true "many-to-many". Business meaning of the UNIT is that it groups BLOCKs with the same processing conditions in the context of the file. So one UNIT can have two BLOCKs from diffrent GROUPs but from the same file.

Comment: Here is the sample of the data. http://pokazywarka.pl/px6786-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information supplied, it appears that this is a true parallel hierarchy. On this basis, I believe that the proposed amended schema would still be normalised to 3NF.

Comment: The original model contained FD's such that a many:many relationship
exists between FILE and UNIT (by virtue of the BLOCK junction). The revised model shows a 1:many relationship between FILE and UNIT. This is a contradiction - something is wrong. Suppose the FILE/UNIT relationship is many:many. This information is already contained in the model, **unless there exist some set of attributes that depend entirely upon the specific FILE/UNIT instance**. If this is not the case, the new model contains redundant relationships and is no longer 3NF.

Comment: @NealB, the existing relationships imply, but do not force, a many to many relationship between FILE and UNIT. The addition of the File ID foreign key resolves this relationship to a **one to many** relationship - at this point, any UNIT can *only* have one FILE. This agrees with the (admittedly small) sample of data supplied by the OP in the fourth comment to the question.

Comment: I see your point - I was distracted by the term "optimized" and assumed the original schema already complete and 3NF with respect to all FD's. From this point of view, adding new relationships must be de-normalizing. Looks like the OP was completing the schema by adding the **UNIT** -> **FILE** FD. As you point out, adding this resolved the Many:Many **UNIT** to **FILE** relationship implied in the original model into a 1:Many. Good work +1

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how the UNIT table fits into the schema before you make changes.

Obviously, after you make changes, all you have to do to know which units belong to a file is join the FILE and UNIT tables.

Since tables are in 3NF when all the functional dependencies are determined by the keys, the whole keys, and nothing but the keys (so help me Codd), you have to look at your schema in that light.

Given the available information, most likely the tables are all in 3NF (and BCNF, and AFAICT in 4NF and 5NF too).

Comment: So help me Codd, I don't think you read the question very carefully.

Comment: -1 Jon: And, It appears you do not know what normalised means.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your "crows foot" diagram supports the
other dependencies outlined in your question. How did you come up
with the 1:Many relationship between FILE and UNIT?

These are the functional dependencies that you describe...

- **GROUP** -> **FILE**
- **BLOCK** -> **GROUP**
- **BLOCK** -> **UNIT**

Also, I assume that each of the above attributes functionally determine some 
additional attributes not appearing
on the left hand side of any other functional dependency. These would be:

- **FILE** -> other-file-attributes
- **GROUP** -> other-group-attributes
- **BLOCK** -> other-block-attributes
- **UNIT** -> other-unit-attributes

Constructing a set of 3NF relations from the above functional dependencies gives:

- FileRelation: (**FILE**, other-file-attributes)
- GroupRelation: (**GROUP**, *FILE*, other-group-attributes)
- UnitRelation: (**UNIT**, other-unit-attributes)
- BlockRelation: (**BLOCK**, *GROUP*, *UNIT*, other-block-attributes)

This pretty much corresponds to what you have described.

Determining which **UNIT** instances relate to a given **FILE**
requires a join of FileRelation to GroupRelation on **FILE** and then GroupRelation to
BlockRelation on **GROUP** then BlockRelation to UnitRelation on **UNIT**.

You want to avoid this multi-table join by inserting a new relationship somewhere in the model that
gives a direct mapping from **UNIT** to **FILE**. Such a relation implies the functional
dependency:

- **UNIT** -> **FILE**

This looks like the bit you added to the "crows foot" diagram. Adding this introduces a logical
contradiction. The original schema supports having a given **UNIT** relating to 
multiple **FILE** instances. as in:

- FileRelation(F1, ...)
- FileRelation(F2, ...)
- GroupRelation(G1, F1, ...)
- GroupRelation(G2, F2, ...)
- BlockRelation(B1, G1, U1, ...)
- BlockRelation(B2, G2, U1, ...)
- UnitRelation(U1, ...)

UNIT instance U1 relates to FILE instances F1 and F2. Given this situation either the **UNIT** -> **FILE** functional dependency cannot be supported
or the original set of functional dependencies were incomplete and the schema is not
in 3NF.

At this point you need to resolve whether the real world supports the **FILE** -> **UNIT**
dependency or not. If it does, then the original model is not in 3NF and a bit more
reworking of the schema is in order. If the dependency is not supported then the best you can say is:

- **FILE**, **UNIT** -> *nothing*

and the corresponding relation:

- FileUnit: (**FILE**, **UNIT**)

is a de-normalization because its content may be derived through existing tables functional dependancies.

**=================================================================================**

**EDIT**

Based on a number of comments made to this and other answers, it appears that:

- **UNIT** -> **FILE**

is a true functional dependency, the functional dependency:

- **BLOCK** -> **UNIT**

while not incorrect, must be redundant. I believe the correct 3NF set of
relations for this model now is:

- FileRelation: (**FILE**, other-file-attributes)
- GroupRelation: (**GROUP**, *FILE*, other-group-attributes)
- UnitRelation: (**UNIT**, *FILE*, other-unit-attributes)
- BlockRelation: (**BLOCK**, *GROUP*, other-block-attributes)

Notice that the **UNIT** foreign key has dropped from the BlockRelation.
This is because the **UNIT** -> **FILE** FD made it redundant. The
(**BLOCK**, **UNIT**) relation is now formed by joining UnitRelation to FileRelation on **FILE**
then FileRelation to GroupRelation on **FILE** then GroupRelation to BlockRelation on **GROUP**.

The original schema was not in 3NF due to the unstated
functional dependency: **UNIT** -> **FILE**. The proposed set of relations above is
in 3NF.

Note: When normalizing a schema, every functional dependency needs to be stated
up front. Missing one can change the whole picture!

Comment: I added the "crows-foot" diagram as an edit - the additional relationship (added as a dotted line) between FILE and UNIT comes from the original question's sentence, "To optimize this schema, I can create the new relation UNIT n--FK-->1 FILE".

Comment: @Mark Bannister: The crows-foot diagram corresponds to the "optomized" schema the OP is asking about so it makes no material difference to my answer.

Comment: @Mark Bannister: I updated my answer based on the determination that UNIT -> FILE is a true functional dependency.

Comment: by removing the Block -> Unit dependancy as redundant, you are now stating that for a File, all Blocks that belong to that File (ie. all Blocks that belong to Groups that belong to that File) are associated with all Units that belongs to that file. However, from the OP's sample data, this is not so - Blocks 1 and 2 are only associated with Unit 1, while Block 3 is only associated with Unit 2. Therefore, the Block -> Unit dependancy is not redundant, and the OP's proposed schema is correctly normalised.